Camera doesn't teleport correctly in build, but does in the editor
I'm making FNAF in unity, and in the editor, I can die and am jumpscared correctly. However, in the build, I'm looking at his feet. See the video below for more context.
I honestly have no clue how to fix this.
I have no clue as to how to make a reproduceable example, since I don't know why it happens.
Post Edit: It's best to just have the jump scare be a different scene, as it's the easiest way to do the jump scare.
Note: Relative coordinates seem to screw up a lot of things, so try to avoid having a camera teleport be a child of an object. If you're just trying an animation (such as a death animation), either use a new scene or just have it be an overlay of a video of the death animation (The death animation in the video should be the 3d one you intended to use)

Please edit the question to include a [mre].

Does the same happen when you build for other platforms like Windows? also if the jumpscare is on a separate scene make sure its included in the build scenes.

Yes. It happens for all builds. I'm currently testing whether or not making the jumpscare a seperate scene will fix it

It's going to be an issue with your build settings or your assigned variables when you built the game.
If the jumpscare is a separate scene, make sure it was included in the build and that the variable reference is set properly at the time of build.
In response to your added info:
Making a new scene should work, but since it is in the same scene already, some alternative options are

setting the camera movement to an exact x,y,z location and rotation
create an empty object where you want the camera to look and use Transform.LookAt on that object (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.LookAt.html)


It's not a seperate scene. Should I make it a seperate scene? I'll try that now

Thank you so much, having it be a different scene worked perfectly
